# Execute function only on component unmount using useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to run a function that has some variables using `useState` inside a function using `useCallback`

This function should only run when component unmounts using the `return` in `useEffect` hook:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useCallback, useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  const update = useCallback(() => {
    console.log({ search });
  }, [search]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      update();
      console.log("I ONLY WANT THIS TO RUN ON UNMOUNT");
    };
  }, [update]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input defaultValue={search} onChange={e => setSearch(e.target.value)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-useeffect-btrbi?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Just get rid of the dependency of ```update```. Your use effect should have an empty dependency array. Currently, anytime that your component re renders and update has changed, your useEffect return statement will run.

Comment: @ChrisShort that won't work as intended, because the reference to `update` will be stale, and so will also reference a stale `search` value.

Comment: @ChrisShort then the `update` function will not see the updated `search` value

Comment: The return inside a `useEffect` will run every time one of the `useEffect`'s dependencies change. Don't think of it like a `componentWillUnmount`, think of it like an effect 'clean-up', that runs whenever a dependency changes. Yes, it _also_ runs as a `componentWillUnmount`, but it does more than that.

Comment: Not sure how else to do it then. With the way useEffect hooks work, any time an item in your dependency array changes, your useEffect will run it's cleanup function which is your return function and then will run the effect again. The useEffect equivalent to componentWillUnmount is to pass an empty dependency array to your useEffect.

Comment: I don't understand the usecase here, why is there a requirement to (1) reference a state value AND (2) only run on unmount? Why is it a problem if the effect runs more than once? And if you only want the effect to run on unmount, why does the effect need to reference the state value? The `useEffect` hook is a tool, and it is not intended to be used in this way. Maybe if you explain what you're trying to achieve, we can find a better way to do it? It feels as though this question is just asking "I want to do this just because" rather than "I want to do this because of X, Y, and Z".

Comment: I'm trying to execute a function that sends an HTTP request to update a form but only want it to run when the component unmounts. It's like a form in a modal, when the modal closes thats when I want it to execute the HTTP request with, in this case, the updated `search` value.

Comment: What happens if the network request fails? Wouldn't you want the form to remain open so the user can try again? Submitting forms on unmount is a big code smell. Surely you want a submit button?

Comment: @JohhanSantana Then keep the state outside of the modal and do the request when the modal gets closed. The modal itself should also be controlled so 1) close the modal on the closing event and 2) submit the values.

Comment: Or as @trixn said, keep state outside of the modal. I still think that firing the function on unmount is the wrong way to go. If you have a close button that closes the modal, why not just fire the submit request when the user clicks the close button? A button can execute more than one function, in this case it closes the modal AND submits the form. Unmounting the modal component should not auto submit a form, because a component unmounting has nothing to do with form submission.

Comment: @JMadelaine I agree with that. Effect cleanups are just the wrong place to do that. They are to clean up what has been subscribed by the component when it mounted/updated. Other things should happen entirely outside of that component.

Comment: yes I see all your valid points. thank you.

Comment: @JohhanSantana It also has the advantage that you can prevent closing the modal (or reopen it) if the request fails for any reason.